# Why does my geth node never start syncing?

Tags: go-ethereum, docker

I'm running a geth node using Docker. I am also running a service that enables authenticated access to port 8545. This is a part of my docker-compose file that is relevant to the geth node:

```
version: "3"

services:
  geth-client:
    image: ethereum/client-go
    ports:
      - 30303:30303
    restart: always
    command: --http --http.addr "0.0.0.0" --http.vhosts=*
    volumes:
      - geth-data:/root/.ethereum
volumes:
  geth-data:
```

Sync mode is `snap` (this is the default one). For some reason, the node never starts to sync. `eth.syncing` is always `false`, eth.blockNumber is  `0` and my balance is `0`. According to the logs, I have 0-3 peers at most in any given moment.

I left the node to run for several hours and there was no change.

I also tried opening 30303/udp, but it didn't have any impact. I can't find anything obvious that is incorrect in the docker-compose file. What am I missing to get the node to work properly? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue, Applying the --nodiscover flag stops the log "Looking for peers" but then the connection fails